# ModuleNotFound error is thrown during debug mode even though folder is present in Intellij IDEA for python projects

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, modulenotfounderror

From the past one week am facing ModuleNotFound error in Intellij for a python project even though the module is present.
I tried several troubleshooting methods.

1. I have added Absolute imports
2. I have set the correct python interpreter
3. Cleared the intelliJ cache and rebuilt the indexes.... still unable to get it fixed.

Please help me resolve this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkKDQ.png)

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the path is in sys.path?

```
import sys
sys.path
```

If the path of the directory your module are missing there simply add it by using

```
sys.path.append('yourpath/')
```

Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to mark the folder as "Test Source Root"?
Please feel free to submit a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY with a simplified project zipped attached and steps to reproduce.